# $_GET & $post_ID

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I got a set of meta boxes containing different form fields. All of them are build inside a set of classes.

Now I have the problem that I have to hook the construction of the fields early enough to hook the needed scripts & styles. Everything is fine - I can display them, styles & scripts appear & work, saving the data works - but I can't retrieve the post meta data to fill the values of the fields.

Point is that the fields get hooked at `admin_menu`, which is too early to get the `$post_id`. Now I saw that I could also use `$_GET['post']` to retrieve the ID.

What speaks against this?

Comment: nothing, use it.... But why do you need the post_id at the `init` point?

Comment: I need it for `get_post_meta( $post_id, etc. );` to fill the values for my form fields if something was already added to the database.

Comment: @One Trick Pony Edit: Class is hooked on `admin_init`. Doesn't make a big difference though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you're in the function that actually prints the html for the metabox, the global $post object should always be set the to current post. Is there a specific reason that you need to know the post_id during init?

Comment: I need it for `get_post_meta( $post_id, etc. );` to fill the values for my form fields if something was already added to the database. So I'm not talking about `$post`, but about `$_GET['post'];` - which I know found out, won't work on other post types as on `'post'`. Any ideas?

Comment: You will not be doing this at init though ... you will be doing it much later in the actual meta box. In the callback function for your metabox you can use global $post or get_post() or get_the_ID() any of these functions should work.

Comment: You shouldn't need the post ID on init, like Michael said you should be filling in form fields at the point of rendering the metabox, which shouldn't be occuring at init(metaboxes also have their own action already, if you're not using it, you should be).

Comment: @mfields @Mark Duncan You can't call scripts or styles from inside a meta box callback. The `add_meta_boxes` hook gets fired long after all enqueue & register hooks happend, so this is too late for (for example: colorpicker) script depended fields. Edit: The class is hooked on `admin_menu`. Not much better.

Comment: In that case i agree, use `$_GET['post']`, though you still don't necessarily need it on init(you're at least not expecting it on **every** page are you?). I'd suggest the `load-{$whateverpage}` hook if this is only for specific admin pages(still early enough to fire off an enqueue).